# Laravel create relationship from an api to a table

Tags: php, laravel, api

Is it possible to create one to one relationships using API?

I have this project and I created API from my table called `LEADS` then inside leads has a column named `lead_id`.

Now in my second project, I have `USER` table then I want to connect `lead_id` to my user table as one to one relationship.

Or if you have a better idea on how to handle this approach I would be glad to consider it, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can create relations in api like routes

Comment: API or not have the same model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple databases, it's quite easy to setup. First add another **connection** in `database.php`.

```
        ...
            'mysql_secondary' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            ...
        ],
```

First, I'm assuming you have 2 models **Lead** and **User**.

To create a relationship between **User** and **Lead**,

```
// user.php
class User extends Authenticatable {
    use Notifiable;
    // the connection defaults to the one set in 'database.php' 
    // (usually specified by DB_CONNECTION)

    public function lead() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Lead::class);
    }
}

// lead.php
class Lead extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'leads';
    // specify the DB connection
    protected $connection = 'mysql_secondary';
}

// to obtain lead from user...
$user = User::find(1);
$lead = $user->lead;
```

I would suggest you visit [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x) as it is a very comprehensive source of documentation, more specifically [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships) to answer your question.

Comment: the lead is from another database that why i created API for leads now in my second database i have user is it possible to make relationship from an API ?

Comment: to make clear LEAD is an API from another database , then user is a table from my current database i want to assign the user to one lead.

Comment: do you have the credentials to the other database?

Comment: then the matter is setting up another DB connection. In **Eloquent** you can override the default connection for each **Model**. Please check answer

Comment: Alright so i don't need to make API i just use the database connection?

Comment: yes, no point in creating an API if you already have the credentials to the database, if not it will greatly slow down your app performance

Comment: so i will just perform JOIN table then in my user table i will add lead_id column to connect  with the table LEAD using it's iD as parameter?

Comment: yes that is correct, it will work if you set up the relationships correctly.